# Literal does not match format string when creating a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep trying to create a basic table. Every time I try to create the table I get the error

> literal does not match format string

I'm trying to limit the years of the tournament between 2005 and 2100.         The error is between DATE '2005'.

This is my code:

```
Create table Tournament_T
(Tournament_name VARCHAR (50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Tournament_year INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT RANGE CHECK (Tournament_year BETWEEN DATE '2005' AND '2100'),
Tournament_rules CLOB NOT NULL,
Tournament_fee VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
Tournment_eligibility VARCHAR (1000) NOT NULL );
COMMIT;
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd734c

Comment: I would suggest you avoid naming your constraint `RANGE` as that is an Oracle reserved word. Also please use `VARCHAR2` and not `VARCHAR`. For the time being their behavior is the same but that could change in the future if Oracle adopts the ANSI SQL standard for `VARCHAR`. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your constraint is using the `date` keyword, but you don't need it.  Just do:

```
CONSTRAINT RANGE CHECK (Tournament_year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2100),
```

Your column is an integer, not a date.